# railsで関連しているモデルのカラムをselectで制御するには

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

`select`を使って取得するカラムを制限したいときに、
関連するモデルのカラムも制御するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

### `belongs_to` のときにやりたいこと

`Post >-- Category`

`Post`の`title`と`Category`の`name`だけを取得したい。

イメージ
`Post.select(:title, :category => name)`

### `has_many` のときにやりたいこと

`Post >-< Tag`

`Post`の`title`と`Tag`の`name`だけを取得したい。

イメージ
`Post.select(:title, :tags => name)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.joins(:category).select('posts.title, categories.name')

Post.joins(:tag).select('posts.title, tags.name')
```

という具合に、キーじゃなくて文字列でかけばいけます。